# React Bootstrap Navbar not showing in one line

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am trying to implement a Navbar in React but when I run it, all elements are shown one under another one, and not in one line. I imported react-bootstrap but it looks like it does not look how it should.
I am new to React, maybe I miss something.

Here is the code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import UserService from '../services/UserService';
import { useLocation, useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Navbar, Nav, NavDropdown, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'

    function EmployeeComponent() {
    
        const [users, setUsers] = useState([])
    
        useEffect(() => {
            getEmployees()
        }, [])
    
        const getEmployees = () => {
            console.log("getEmployee");
            UserService.getUsers().then((response) => {
                setUsers(response.data)
                console.log(response.data);
            });
        };
    
        const location = useLocation();
        const [searchParam] = useSearchParams();
    
        return (
    
            <div className="container">
    
                <Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
                    
                        <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
                        <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
                        <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                            <Nav className="me-auto">
                                <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
                                <Nav.Link href="#link">Link</Nav.Link>
                                <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                                    <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
                                    <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">Another action</NavDropdown.Item>
                                    <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Something</NavDropdown.Item>
                                    <NavDropdown.Divider />
                                    <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">Separated link</NavDropdown.Item>
                                </NavDropdown>
                            </Nav>
                        </Navbar.Collapse>
                   
                </Navbar>
```

How it looks on my screen: [image]
How it should look like: [image]

Comment: Doesn't look like the CSS is loading.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a problem, but you have your container and primary navbar elements inverted. See https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar.

Comment: You have to import the bootstrap css aswell: `import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";`